# Is it better to purchase 1password from agilebits website or the app store?

Tags: mac-appstore, license, password

Is it better value to purchase 1password from the https://agilebits.com/ website or the app store?

They cost different amounts, does the app store version include all future versions of 1password?

Which is the best option for consumers based on the license terms of the Mac App store versus a third party license where you buy an app directly from the vendor?

(I have checked the agilebits.com website, but cannot find this information)

Comment: See https://agilebits.com/home/licenses

Comment: This is very much on-topic once it gets an edit to narrow down what "best" means. Anyone can have an opinion so without knowing what best is to pingu - this can have as many answers as people care to form an opinion.

Comment: See : http://learn.agilebits.com/1Password4/Mac/en/KB/where_to_purchase.html

Comment: Also a guide of How to migrate from the MAS version to the web store version: http://learn.agilebits.com/1Password4/Mac/en/KB/mas-web.html

Comment: Standalone version cannot use iCloud for sync.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are benefits to both sides:

- The Mac App Store's 1Password has iCloud syncing whereas the AgileBits store distribution method can't include iCloud syncing since an app must be distributed through the Mac App Store to use such Apple services.
- The AgileBits store's 1Password is updated more frequently since the updates don't have to go through Apple's approval system. This also means you can get beta updates that aren't on the Mac App Store due to Apple's guidelines on beta distribution.

Comment: Additionally, the second option gives more of your money to AgileBits vs. Apple.

Answer (score 2):

http://learn.agilebits.com/1Password4/Mac/en/KB/where_to_purchase.html

> Should I purchase on the Mac App Store or from your website?
>
> To use iCloud syncing you should purchase on the Mac App Store, but
>   ultimately the choice is a personal preference. Using the Mac App
>   Store makes it easier since you don’t need to keep track of a license
>   key. On the other hand, purchasing from our website is also great
>   since 1Password provides a great way to keep track of software license
>   keys, and you will receive updates faster as we approve them directly.